# Mapbox map.on('load') is extremely slow

Tags: javascript, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I have a web app I am creating that maps 30k+ symbols, but my issue is that on initialization, the map.on('load') is way too slow. I've added timers all throughout my code and it is specifically this line of code that takes 10+ seconds to run.

I've looked through all of Mapbox's resources on performance but none of the suggestions work or are relevant, (e.g., minimize the amount of layers used even though my layers take 0.1 seconds to load, using vector tiles instead of GeoJSON data, changing the properties of the data source, minimizing features etc.).

Has anyone else had this issue and figured out how to resolve it? I've been trying for days to optimize this map but I can't figure it out!

```
// Set map properties with the predefined configuration
mapboxgl.accessToken =  'my access token';
    const map = new mapboxgl.Map({
        container: 'fullMap',
        style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/light-v10',
        center: [-100.83, 39.22], 
        zoom: 5,
    });

    startTime = performance.now();

    map.on('load', () => {

        endTime = performance.now(); // Ends up being 10+ seconds...

        map.addSource('gc_offices', {
            type: 'geojson',
            data: geojsonData,
            buffer: 0,
            cluster: true,
            clusterMaxZoom: 12, // Max zoom to cluster points on
            clusterRadius: 50,  // Radius of each cluster when clustering points 
        });
        
        map.addLayer({
            id: 'clusters',
            type: 'circle',
            source: 'gc_offices',
            paint: {
                'circle-color': [
                    'step',
                    ['get', 'point_count'],
                    '#2288f2',
                    5, '#3d97f5',
                    25, '#64abf5',
                    50, '#83bcf7',
                    100, '#a3ccf7',
                    250, '#cfe4fa',
                    500, '#eb4034'
                ],
                'circle-radius': [
                    'step',
                    ['get', 'point_count'],
                    13,
                    20, 18,
                    50, 25,
                    100, 30,
                    250, 40,
                    500, 50,
                ]
             }
        });

        map.addLayer({
            id: 'cluster-count',
            type: 'symbol',
            source: 'gc_offices',
            filter: ['has', 'point_count'],
            layout: {
                'text-field': '{point_count_abbreviated}',
                'text-font': ['DIN Offc Pro Medium', 'Arial Unicode MS Bold'],
                'text-size': 12,
                'text-allow-overlap': true
            }
        });

        map.addLayer({
            id: 'locationData',
            type: 'symbol',
            source: 'gc_offices',
            minzoom: 10,
            layout: gc_office_layout_properties,
            paint: gc_office_paint_properties,
        });
    });
```

Comment: What is the actual problem you are trying to solve? Is it that the map takes a long time to display? Or takes a long time to be ready to add more layers?

Comment: Well it's technically both. The underlying map does not show up until the line map.on('load', () is done, and the layers cannot be added until that line is complete. But mainly the map taking too long to display.

Comment: Your description of the problem does not seem plausible. You're loading a standard Mapbox style, in an apparently standard way, and saying it takes 10 seconds to load.  Everything you've included in your code snippet after the load isn't relevant. You need to provide a Codepen or similar to show the issue. If it's real, it's caused by something you haven't explained so far.